# Django - Reverse a queryset

Tags: django, reverse

I have very basic view with queryset, but for some reason I cannot reverse it.

```
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().reverse()
    return render(request, "home.html", {'posts': posts})
```

For some reason no matter how I change code -  instanses from queryset always rendering in same order.
Below there are lines of code that I already tried and which didn't worked for some reason:

```
Post.objects.all().reverse()
Post.objects.order_by('-date')
Post.objects.order_by('date').reverse()
```

**home.html:**

```
{% for post in posts %}
{{ post.title }}
{{ post.content }}
{% endfor %}
```

**models.py:**

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
    image = models.URLField(blank=True, null=True, unique=True)
    content = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
    date = models.DateField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)
    #To make in name, not objXXX
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: Do you have any objects that have different date

Answer (score 0):

I believe the queryset you're looking for is `Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")`:

```py
def home(request):
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by("-date")
    return render(request, "home.html", {"posts": posts})
```

It is considered a best practice to avoid putting `ordering` on a Django model, as it can force unnecessary sorting operations in the database when you don't need them. When necessary, I put default `ordering` on Django Admin definitions, instead of the model. Good luck!

Comment: OP already stated that he tried to use that exact order_by also there is no need for .all()

Comment: Explicit is better than implicit, and not having the `.all()` by definition makes it `not exact`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is the ordering that you are looking for try (in models.py):

```
class Meta:
    ordering = ('-date',)
```

If not, it does not mean much to reverse something that isn't ordered, try (in views.py):

This

```
post = Post.objects.filter("<filter name>").reverse()
```

instead of

```
post =  Post.objects.all.order_by("<field name>").reverse()
```